# Nginx returns incorrect date format to controller

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, datetimepicker

I have problem with datetimepicker. I need to pass datetime in dd/mm/yyyy format to my controller but my nginx passes date in mm/dd/yyyy format. Because of this my controller returns error "The value '25/08/2019' is not valid for StartDate".

How can I change date format of my nginx proxy?

P.S I tried to debug this error on my computer but everything works fine, so problem is in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in locale of my ubuntu server. So I changed locale to en_DK by running next command in terminal

```
export LC_ALL=en_DK.utf8
```

and everything start to work fine

Comment: That's one option. The other option is having your application convert it for you. Which I believe is a more resilient option.